# How to waterproof log store base?

Tags: wood, base

[image]

Im planning a 200x80 log store out of treated 6x2 on concrete slabs similar to the image above. How do i stop the damp from creeping through the structure?

- There will be 20mm overhand all sides but still not confident that will stop damp.

Comment: 20mm is not much for an overhang, 20cm would be better.  Damp is a problem if it stays damp, good ventilation is needed.

Comment: Place some sort of metal or plastic between the concrete bricks and the wooden frame.

Comment: I assume you are not installing any siding, in that case you need good overhang,  combined with some awning.  That would be most effective to keep your firewood from getting wet due to heavy rain, especially sideways.

Comment: First of all, increase the hight to 1-2 feet. Not only it will stop creatures like rats nesting under, but it will provide more ventilation

Comment: Yes overhand will be 20cm front, 10cm sides and rear. Would rubber feet work raising the structure 1cm from ground? They will go through the supporting timbers

Comment: Built one similar, but just had rails for the “floor”. As for sideways rain - that tends to dry off with the wind. My construction was much cheaper: 6 metal poles stuck in the ground, three rails across and 2 long, then cheap roofing corrugated panels. However, mine is not close to a building so ventilation from all sides is assured.